# CouchDB on docker desktop for OSX fails to start

Tags: macos, docker, couchdb

I'm trying to install CouchDB on docker desktop for OSX.  I follow the following steps:

`docker pull couchdb` (which works)

I then start the docker image:

```
docker run -d --name test-couchdb couchdb:latest
```

The log reports this:

> [notice] 2019-08-30T10:27:03.039090Z nonode@nohost <0.325.0> --------
>   chttpd_auth_cache changes listener died database_does_not_exist at
>   mem3_shards:load_shards_from_db/6(line:395) <=
>   mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/1(line:370) <=
>   mem3_shards:load_shards_from_disk/2(line:399) <=
>   mem3_shards:for_docid/3(line:86) <= fabric_doc_open:go/3(line:39) <=
>   chttpd_auth_cache:ensure_auth_ddoc_exists/2(line:195) <=
>   chttpd_auth_cache:listen_for_changes/1(line:142) [error]
>   2019-08-30T10:27:03.039976Z nonode@nohost emulator -------- Error in
>   process <0.461.0> with exit value:
>   {database_does_not_exist,[{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_db,"_users",[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,395}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,1,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,370}]},{mem3_shards,load_shards_from_disk,2,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,399}]},{mem3_shards,for_docid,3,[{file,"src/mem3_shards.erl"},{line,86}]},{fabric_doc_open,go,3,[{file,"src/fabric_doc_open.erl"},{line,39}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,ensure_auth_ddoc_exists,2,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,195}]},{chttpd_auth_cache,listen_for_changes,1,[{file,"src/chttpd_auth_cache.erl"},{line,142}]}]}
>
> [notice] 2019-08-30T10:27:03.065708Z nonode@nohost <0.347.0> --------
>   couch_replicator_clustering : cluster stable [notice]
>   2019-08-30T10:27:03.073623Z nonode@nohost <0.360.0> -------- Started
>   replicator db changes listener <0.462.0>

Seems like an Erlang error.
When I do `curl http://127.0.0.1:5984` or `curl localhost:5984` I get a connection refused message both times, probably because the listener is not up and running....

I'm thinking this is an incompatibility issue, but not sure

---

This is a simple attempt to get another container started:
Vans-MacBook-Pro:~ vw$

`docker pull couchdb`

Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/couchdb
Digest: sha256:7537a9047fea8960ed9e88123a2cb9cbd96db51767f9a9b3ccfcb174b11408c1
Status: Image is up to date for couchdb:latest
docker.io/library/couchdb:latest

vw$ `docker run -d --name my2-couchdb couchdb`
2e2e37c8fb6b63ebbdc874396ce64a22727706237cb05bdbf256e4048f3346ef

vw$ docker `run -p 5984:5984 -d my2-couchdb`
Unable to find image 'my2-couchdb:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for my2-couchdb, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.

Comment: Does the container actually exit?  Without a `docker run -p` option to publish the container's ports, you won't be able to reach it in any case.

Comment: Yes it does.  I added another run to the body of the issue.  Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, got it to work by including admin username/password and port, like this:

```
docker run -d --name couchdb -e COUCHDB_USER=admin -e COUCHDB_PASSWORD=password -p 5984:5984 couchdb:latest
```